# AttributeError: 'FFmpegPCMAudio' object has no attribute '_process' but ffmpeg.exe is installed in the working directory

Tags: ffmpeg, pycord

```
@bot.slash_command(name="say", description="Convert text to speech", default_permissions=False)
@commands.check(check_role)
async def say(ctx, lang: Option(str, "Choose a language", autocomplete=showlangs), text: Option(str, "Enter text to convert to speech")):
    global temp
    await ctx.defer()
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    author = ctx.author.id
    authorname = ctx.author.name
    authornick = ctx.author.display_name
    lang = lang.lower()
    texta = text.lower()
    if not lang in lang_list:
        config.read(os.path.join(configs, str(ctx.guild.id)), encoding='utf-8')
        lang = config['DEFAULT']['defvoice']
    if "gg" in texta and "it" in lang:
        texta = re.sub(r"\bgg\b", "g g", texta)
    texta = "".join(texta)
    user = re.findall(r"<@!?(\d+)>", texta)
    if user:
        for x in user:
            try:
                u = await bot.fetch_user(int(x))
            except:
                texta = re.sub(r"<@!?({})>".format(x), "Invalid User", texta)
                continue
            texta = re.sub(r"<@!?({})>".format(x), u.name, texta)
                
    chann = re.findall(r"<#(\d+)>", texta)
    if chann:
        for x in chann:
            try:
                c = await bot.fetch_channel(int(x))
            except:
                texta = re.sub(r"<#({})>".format(x), "Invalid Channel", texta)
                continue
            texta = re.sub(r"<#({})>".format(x), c.name, texta)
    role = re.findall(r"<@&(\d+)>", texta)
    if role:
        for x in role:
            try:
                r = ctx.guild.get_role(int(x))
            except:
                texta = re.sub(r"<@&({})>".format(x), "Invalid Role", texta)
                continue
            texta = re.sub(r"<@&({})>".format(x), r.name, texta)
    texta = re.sub(r"<\/(\w+):(\d+)>", r"\1", texta)
    texta = re.sub(r"<a?:(\w+):(\d+)>", r"\1", texta)
    texta = re.sub(r"<:(\w+):(\d+)>", r"\1", texta)
    time1 = re.findall(r"<t:(\d+)>", texta)
    if time1:
        for x in time1:
            t = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x))
            texta = re.sub(r"<t:({})>".format(x), t.strftime("%A %d %B %Y, %H:%M:%S"), texta)
    time2 = re.findall(r"<t:(\d+):(\w+)>", texta)
    if time2:
        for x in time2:
            t = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x[0]))
            texta = re.sub(r"<t:({}):({})>".format(x[0], x[1]), t.strftime("%A %d %B %Y, %H:%M:%S"), texta)
    users = []
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(temp, str(ctx.guild.id), ".users")):
        with open(os.path.join(temp, str(ctx.guild.id), ".users"), "rb") as f:
            users = pickle.load(f)
        if not author in users:
            users.append(author)
            with open(os.path.join(temp, str(ctx.guild.id), ".users"), "wb") as f:
                pickle.dump(users, f)
        if len(users) > 1:
            config.read(os.path.join(configs, str(ctx.guild.id)), encoding='utf-8')
            if config['DEFAULT']['multiuser'] == "True":
                if config['DEFAULT']['usenicknames'] == "True":
                    texta = f"{authornick}: {texta}"
                else:
                    texta = f"{authorname}: {texta}"
    else:
        users.append(author)
        with open(os.path.join(temp, str(ctx.guild.id), ".users"), "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(users, f)
    tts = gTTS(texta, lang=lang)
    if os.name == 'nt':
        source = f"{temp}\{ctx.guild.id}\{ran()}.mp3"
    else:
        source = f"{temp}/{ctx.guild.id}/{ran()}.mp3"
    try:
        tts.save(source)
    except gTTSError:
        code = generate_random_code()
        e = traceback.format_exc()
        print(e + "Error Code: " + code)
        embed = discord.Embed(title=eval("f" + get_guild_language(ctx, 'errtitle')), description=eval("f" + get_guild_language(ctx, 'unexpectederror')), color=0xFF0000)
        await ctx.respond(embed=embed, delete_after=5)
        return
    if await preplay(ctx, source):
        embed=discord.Embed(title=eval("f" + get_guild_language(ctx, 'done')), description=eval("f" + get_guild_language(ctx, 'saylangmess')), color=0x1eff00)
        await ctx.respond(embed=embed, allowed_mentions=discord.AllowedMentions(replied_user=False))

async def hidsay(ctx, lang, text):
    global temp
    await ctx.defer()
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    author = ctx.author.id
    authorname = ctx.author.name
    authornick = ctx.author.display_name
    lang = lang.lower()
    texta = text.lower()
    if not lang in lang_list:
        config.read(os.path.join(configs, str(ctx.guild.id)), encoding='utf-8')
        lang = config['DEFAULT']['defvoice']
    if "gg" in texta and "it" in lang:
        texta = re.sub(r"\bgg\b", "g g", texta)
    texta = "".join(texta)
    if texta == "" or texta.isspace():
        embed = discord.Embed(title=eval("f" + get_guild_language(ctx, 'errtitle')), description=eval("f" + get_guild_language(ctx, 'errnoarg')), color=0xFF0000)
        await ctx.respond(embed=embed, delete_after=5)
        return
    user = re.findall(r"<@!?(\d+)>", texta)
    if user:
        for x in user:
            try:
                u = await bot.fetch_user(int(x))
            except:
                texta = re.sub(r"<@!?({})>".format(x), "Invalid User", texta)
                continue
            texta = re.sub(r"<@!?({})>".format(x), u.name, texta)
                
    chann = re.findall(r"<#(\d+)>", texta)
    if chann:
        for x in chann:
            try:
                c = await bot.fetch_channel(int(x))
            except:
                texta = re.sub(r"<#({})>".format(x), "Invalid Channel", texta)
                continue
            texta = re.sub(r"<#({})>".format(x), c.name, texta)
    role = re.findall(r"<@&(\d+)>", texta)
    if role:
        for x in role:
            try:
             r = ctx.guild.get_role(int(x))
            except:
                texta = re.sub(r"<@&({})>".format(x), "Invalid Role", texta)
                continue
            texta = re.sub(r"<@&({})>".format(x), r.name, texta)
    texta = re.sub(r"<\/(\w+):(\d+)>", r"\1", texta)
    texta = re.sub(r"<a?:(\w+):(\d+)>", r"\1", texta)
    texta = re.sub(r"<:(\w+):(\d+)>", r"\1", texta)
    time1 = re.findall(r"<t:(\d+)>", texta)
    if time1:
        for x in time1:
            t = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x))
            texta = re.sub(r"<t:({})>".format(x), t.strftime("%A %d %B %Y, %H:%M:%S"), texta)
    time2 = re.findall(r"<t:(\d+):(\w+)>", texta)
    if time2:
        for x in time2:
            t = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x[0]))
            texta = re.sub(r"<t:({}):({})>".format(x[0], x[1]), t.strftime("%A %d %B %Y, %H:%M:%S"), texta)
    users = []
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(temp, str(ctx.guild.id), ".users")):
        with open(os.path.join(temp, str(ctx.guild.id), ".users"), "rb") as f:
            users = pickle.load(f)
        if not author in users:
            users.append(author)
            with open(os.path.join(temp, str(ctx.guild.id), ".users"), "wb") as f:
                pickle.dump(users, f)
        if len(users) > 1:
            config.read(os.path.join(configs, str(ctx.guild.id)), encoding='utf-8')
            if config['DEFAULT']['multiuser'] == "True":
                if config['DEFAULT']['usenicknames'] == "True":
                    texta = f"{authornick}: {texta}"
                else:
                    texta = f"{authorname}: {texta}"
    else:
        users.append(author)
        with open(os.path.join(temp, str(ctx.guild.id), ".users"), "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(users, f)
    tts = gTTS(texta, lang=lang)
    if os.name == 'nt':
        source = f"{temp}\{ctx.guild.id}\{ran()}.mp3"
    else:
        source = f"{temp}/{ctx.guild.id}/{ran()}.mp3"
    try:
        tts.save(source)
    except gTTSError:
        code = generate_random_code()
        e = traceback.format_exc()
        print(e + "Error Code: " + code)
        embed = discord.Embed(title=eval("f" + get_guild_language(ctx, 'errtitle')), description=eval("f" + get_guild_language(ctx, 'unexpectederror')), color=0xFF0000)
        await ctx.respond(embed=embed, delete_after=5)
        return
    if await preplay(ctx, source):
        embed=discord.Embed(title=eval("f" + get_guild_language(ctx, 'done')), description=eval("f" + get_guild_language(ctx, 'saylangmess')), color=0x1eff00)
        await ctx.respond(embed=embed, allowed_mentions=discord.AllowedMentions(replied_user=False), delete_after=1, silent=True)
```

bot doesn't play when the say command is used. ffmpeg says not found, but ffmpeg.exe is installed in the working directory. I installed the working excecutable file from ffmpeg build website for Windows 10, yet it still doesn't work. I can't figure out what's happening. I'm using Pycord.

The terminal also mentions  this

```
  proc = self._process
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'FFmpegPCMAudio' object has no attribute '_process'
```